# How to change a dimension when object has been rotated

Tags: edit-mode

[image]I have a simple object (mesh cube changed to a rectangular shape eg plank of wood) which has previously been rotated and I want to increase one dimension (thickness). When I change the dimension the edges do not retain the previous angle and become more vertical.  How can I change a dimension without changing the angles?
Refer exampled below where I changed the 'thickness' (Z axis).
Also is it possible to 'measure' the rotation angle of an existing mesh eg a plank of wood leaning against a wall how to measure that angle?
Thanks

Comment: Keep it to one question at a time. Anyways, that’s not rotation, that’s shear. Scaling would indeed change the angles. What you need is to go into edit mode and move the tilted faces along the axis parallel to the un-titled edges of this parallelogram.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't understand about 'shear' as the mesh was originally ROTATED before modifying the Z dimension (which resulted in what you see in the image). I couldn't get my head around your solution (after trying) and so started again adding a mesh cube, changing the dimensions to what I wanted and then rotating before applying all transforms. I now understand that once the transforms have been applied modifications are 'tricky' and so should not be applied until one is completely satisfied.

Comment: have you applied the rotation and scale in Object mode (Ctrl A)?

Comment: Yes. I now think that once you apply transforms (Ctrl A then select scale, rotation or all transforms) then other 'things'/adjustments can become difficult similar to after you apply modifiers and as such should only be applied when you are happy with what you have done so far.